# QProcess dies for no obvious reason

Tags: qt, pipe, qprocess

While coding a seemingly simple part of a Qt application that would run a subprocess and read data from its standard output, I have stumbled upon a problem that has me really puzzled. The application should read blocks of data (raw video frames) from the subprocess and process them as they arrive:

1. start a QProcess
2. gather data until there is enough for one frame
3. process the frame
4. return to step 2

The idea was to implement the processing loop using signals and slots – this might look silly in the simple, stripped-down example that I provide below, but seemed entirely reasonable within the framework of the original application. So here we go:

```
app::app() {
  process.start("cat /dev/zero");
  buffer = new char[frameLength];
  connect(this, SIGNAL(wantNewFrame()), SLOT(readFrame()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
  connect(this, SIGNAL(frameReady()), SLOT(frameHandler()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
  emit wantNewFrame();
}
```

I start here a trivial process (`cat /dev/zero`) so that we can be confident that it will not run out of data. I also make two connections: one starts the reading when a frame is needed and the other calls a data handling function upon the arrival of a frame. Note that this trivial example runs in a single thread so the connections are made to be of the queued type to avoid infinite recursion. The `wantNewFrame()` signal initiates the acquisition of the first frame; it gets handled when the control returns to the event loop.

```
bool app::readFrame() {
  qint64 bytesNeeded = frameLength;
  qint64 bytesRead = 0;
  char* ptr = buffer;
  while (bytesNeeded > 0) {
    process.waitForReadyRead();
    bytesRead = process.read(ptr, bytesNeeded);
    if (bytesRead == -1) {
      qDebug() << "process state" << process.state();
      qDebug() << "process error" << process.error();
      qDebug() << "QIODevice error" << process.errorString();
      QCoreApplication::quit();
      break;
    }
    ptr += bytesRead;
    bytesNeeded -= bytesRead;
  }
  if (bytesNeeded == 0) {
    emit frameReady();
    return true;
  } else
    return false;
}
```

Reading the frame: basically, I just stuff the data into a buffer as it arrives. The `frameReady()` signal at the end announces that the frame is ready and in turn causes the data handling function to run.

```
void app::frameHandler() {
  static qint64 frameno = 0;
  qDebug() << "frame" << frameno++;
  emit wantNewFrame();
}
```

A trivial data processor: it just counts the frames. When it is done, it emits `wantNewFrame()` to start the reading cycle anew.

This is it. For completeness, I'll also post the header file and main() here.

app.h:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>

class app : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
  app();
  ~app() { delete[] buffer; }

signals:
  void wantNewFrame();
  void frameReady();

public slots:
  bool readFrame();
  void frameHandler();

private:
  static const quint64 frameLength = 614400;
  QProcess process;
  char* buffer;
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "app.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QCoreApplication coreapp(argc, argv);
    app foo;
    return coreapp.exec();
}
```

And now for the bizarre part. This program processes a random number of frames just fine (I've seen anything from fifteen to more than thousand) but eventually stops and complains that the QProcess had crashed:

```
$ ./app
frame 1
...
frame 245 
frame 246 
frame 247 
process state 0 
process error 1 
QIODevice error "Process crashed"
```

Process state 0 means "not running" and process error 1 means "crashed". I investigated into it and found out that the child process receives a SIGPIPE – i.e., the parent had closed the pipe on it. But I have *absolutely no* idea of where and why this happens. Does anybody else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is a bit weird looking (not using the `readyRead` signal and instead relying on delayed signals/slots). As you pointed out in the discussion, you've already seen the [thread on the qt-interest ML](http://lists.qt.nokia.com/public/qt-interest/2009-May/006354.html) where I asked about a similar problem. I've just realized that I, too, used the `QueuedConnection` at that time. I cannot explain why it is wrong -- the queued signals "should work", in my opinion. A blind shot is that the `invokeMethod` which is used by the Qt's implementation somehow races with your signal delivery so that you empty your read buffer before Qt gets a chance to process the data. This would mean that Qt will ultimately read zero bytes and (correctly) interpret that as an `EOF`, closing the pipe.

I cannot find the referenced "Qt task 217111" anymore, but there is a couple of reports in their Jira about `waitForReadyRead` not working as users expect, see e.g. [QTBUG-9529](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-9529).

I'd bring this to the Qt's "interest" mailing list anmd stay clear of the `waitFor...` family of methods. I agree that their documentation deserves updating.

Comment: Neat suggestion, but unfortunately I did not get much helpful information from strace. It did confirm, however, that the pipe is indeed being closed. I am starting to believe that I might not be doing anything wrong and that the problem occurs due to some internal race condition on Qt's part.

Comment: That's a dangerous conclusion -- and as someone who tried to rewrite QProcess with Posix syscalls just for fun, I do acknowledge it can be very tempting one :). Surely you can see a ``close()`` in the output of ``strace``. If that's not enough to figure out why this happens, you can always run the whole thing under  a debugger like ``gdb`` and set a breakpoint/catchpoint in ``close``.

Comment: I dug around Qt's code somewhat and I did find out where the close() gets called. Now... HAHAHA! I was about to paste a link to an e-mail thread on Qt-interest that is possibly related to this problem and have just now recognised that it was you who started the thread. :-) Well, [here](http://lists.qt.nokia.com/public/qt-interest/2009-May/006341.html) is the link anyway. My impression of what is happening is that the main event loop somehow gets a spurious notification about new data waiting at the pipe, only to find out that there is nothing really there.

Comment: Ah :), now that definitely rings a bell -- thanks for reminding me. The issue in my code was (as Thiago pointed out in other replies in that thread) that I was essentially calling ``waitForReadyRead`` from a slot attached to the ``readyRead`` signal (read the linked Qt bug tracker for details; they have special workarounds in some of their classes for just this).
I'd suggest changing your code so that it listens to the ``QProcess::readyRead`` signal instead and checks the ``bytesAvailable``, return early if not enough data is there and rely on re-emitting the readyRead signal for processing.

Comment: I already thought about rewriting the code to listen to `QProcess::readyRead` as you suggested but I first wanted to know what the problem was with the current implementation. The motivation of "this does not work, let's try to do it another way" just did not seem good enough to me. I was hoping that the Qt documentation said somewhere "you should not do this-and-this or bad things will happen" and that I had somehow overlooked it. But I have not found such an explanation yet. That's why I say that it seems like a bug to me; I just don't feel that I'm doing anything that I shouldn't be.

Comment: I'd suggest raising this on the Qt's ``interest`` mailing list. If you suspect there's a bug in an open source software, it's great to ask its developers. They will also likely respond with a better response than me.

Comment: I'll certainly do that. Jan, thanks for your comments; it was good to see a second opinion so that I can be more certain that I am not having some obvious fundamental mistake in the code. I also think that something along the lines of your last comment ("contact the developers if you suspect a bug") is actually a suitable and helpful suggestion in cases such as this one, so if you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.